# How to avoid triggering an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while parsing empty positions in a line of CSV?

Tags: java, exception, csv, string-parsing, indexoutofboundsexception

```
String[] values = line.split(",");

Long locId = Long.parseLong(replaceQuotes(values[0]));
String country = replaceQuotes(values[1]);
String region = replaceQuotes(values[2]);
String city = replaceQuotes(values[3]);
String postalCode = replaceQuotes(values[4]);
String latitude = replaceQuotes(values[5]);
String longitude = replaceQuotes(values[6]);
String metroCode = replaceQuotes(values[7]);
String areaCode = replaceQuotes(values[8]);

//...

public String replaceQuotes(String txt){
    txt = txt.replaceAll("\"", "");
    return txt;
}
```

I'm using the code above to parse a CSV with data in this format:

```
828,"US","IL","Melrose Park","60160",41.9050,-87.8641,602,708
```

However, when I encounter a line of data such as the following I get **`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7`**

```
1,"O1","","","",0.0000,0.0000,,
```

Does this mean that any time I even try to access the value at `values[7]`, an Exception will be thrown?

If so, how do I parse lines that don't contain data in that position of the text line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `String.split()` is not a great CSV parser: it doesn't know about quotes and will mess up as soon as one of your quoted values contains a comma.

That being said, by default [`String.split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) leaves out empty trailing elements. You can influence that by using [the two-argument variant](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
String[] values = line.split(",", -1);
```

- `-1` (or any negative value) means that the array will be as large as necessary.
- Using a positive value gives a maximum amount of splits to be done (meaning that everything beyond that will be a single value, even if it contains a comma).
- `0` (the default if you use the one-argument value) means that the array will be as large as necessary, *but* empty trailing values will be left out of the array (exactly as it happens to you).

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule you should never, ever hack up your own (faulty) parser if a working one already exists. CSV is not easy to parse correctly, and String.split will not do the job since CSV allows `,` to be used between `"`'s without working as separaters.

Consider using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). This will solve both the problem you have now and the problem you will face when a user uses a `,` as part of the data.